# Text input value as css

Tags: javascript, html, input

So, I want a text area that works as a css input area. When css is typed into the area, my plan is for it to change the html inside of an output div. How would I make the input's value (text inside of the input) act as css code? I would prefer if it was in javascript.

My code so far...

```
var html = document.getElementById("inputHTML").value; 
var css = document.getElementById("inputCSS").value; 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html; 
document.getElementById("output").style = css;
```

Comment: Trigger on keyup, perhaps. What have you tried?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://projects.decodingweb.com/LivEdit/)? Than the source is open for you, it's from one of my on going projects... You can get the git link from my profile

Comment: I have tried;var html =         document.getElementById("inputHTML").value;
    var css = document.getElementById("inputCSS").value;
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
    document.getElementById("output").style = css;

Comment: You can use element.style.cssText property to put inline styles

Comment: What is a " css input area" ? :-)

Comment: Hm, is it a solution to use a completely another solution instead of solving your problem in your code? well, then you can also use something like https://github.com/jsbin/jsbin/ instead of reinventing the wheel. Did my answer not solve your initial problem?

Comment: I tried your code but it didn't look like it fixed it. It may be due to other bugs that I had thought, I think my src was scr. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
var html = document.getElementById("inputHTML").value;
var css = document.getElementById("inputCSS").value;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
document.getElementById("output").style.cssText  = css;
```

should do the trick

also JSCSSP is maybe an alternative: http://glazman.org/JSCSSP/

It parses and reserializes your CSS code

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write up something yourself like this:

HTML:

```
<label for="area">only css here:</label>
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
<hr/>
<div id="apply-css">
    <form id="bum">
        <label for="bumtext">SomeText</label>
        <input id="bumtext" type="text" />
        <button id="bumbtn">SomeButton</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var cssArea = document.getElementById("area");
var applyCssAreaDiv = document.getElementById("apply-css");
// reload as soon as focus is lost
function onFocusLost() {
    var cssText = cssArea.value;
    console.log(cssText);
    // TODO: validate css before applying  Left as an Exercise!:-)
    var allStylesOnPage = document.getElementsByTagName("style"),
        oldMyDynamicStyle = document.getElementById("myDynamicStyle");
    if (oldMyDynamicStyle) { // delete any existing style with #myDynamicStyle
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].removeChild(oldMyDynamicStyle);
    }
    // create our css from text area text
    var newStyle = document.createElement("style");
    newStyle.setAttribute("id", "myDynamicStyle");
    newStyle.innerHTML = cssText;

    //stick it back into the DOM as last "style" element
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newStyle);

}

// as soon as you tab out of css area your styles will applied!!    
cssArea.addEventListener("blur", onFocusLost);
```

Some CSS just so that you could see how it is overridden:

```
form#bum {
    padding: 60 60;
}
form >label {
    font: bold Arial #CCC;
}
button {
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Dy2z/34/) to see it all working together